# Node.js, 'event loop`, setTimeout does not work as I expect

Tags: node.js

Please have a look at code below:

```
setTimeout(() => {console.log('A')}, 3000);
setTimeout(() => {console.log('B')}, 1000);
setTimeout(() => {console.log('C')}, 500);
```

since `setTimeout` adds message to `message queue` and messages are `FIFO` queue, and one message needs to finish before next one may start, I expect to see `A B C` order but I see `C B A`.

It means that I do not understand something here. What is it that I do not understand?

Comment: The callback is added to the queue after the given timeout, so setTimeout with 500ms timeout will be added to the queue first, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setTimeout` is provided to us by the Web API: it lets us delay tasks without blocking the main thread. The callback doesn’t immediately get added to the call stack. It simply gets added to the queue after `setTimeout` time.

In [this](https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-event-loop-3dif) article you can have more details and visualization about `event loop`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

> The function setTimeout is called with 2 arguments: a message to add
> to the queue, and a time value (optional; defaults to 0). The time
> value represents the (minimum) delay after which the message will be
> pushed into the queue. If there is no other message in the queue, and
> the stack is empty, the message is processed right after the delay.

That means the `message queue` also knows how to handle the delays.